# How to extends basic type with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to extend the Date type for re-use easily in my whole application.

Problems : It doesn't woork and I don't understand why.
Here we go.

My declaration in `date.ts` : (the `ressources` var is a i18n file)

```
export interface Date {
    toDate: (locale: string) => string;
    toTime: (locale: string) => string;
    toDateTime: (locale: string, useText?: boolean) => string;
}

Object.defineProperties(Date.prototype, {
    toDate: {
        value: function (locale: string) {
            return this.toLocaleDateString(locale, { day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", year: "numeric" });
        },
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    },
    toTime: {
        value: function (locale: string) {
            return this.toLocaleDateString(locale, { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" }).substring(0, 5);
        },
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    },
    toDateTime: {
        value: function (locale: string, useText: boolean = false) {
            return useText
                ? `${ressources.message.events.the} ${this.toDate(locale)} ${ressources.message.events.at} ${this.toTime(locale)}`
                : `${this.toDate(locale)} ${this.toTime(locale)}`;
        },
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    }
});
```

But when I want to use it :

[image]

> Property 'toDateTime' does not exist on type 'Date'

What did I miss here ?

I use vuejs, so maybe can I declare it global or something ?

Comment: Extending a global would make more sense because you really extend a global. And be aware that polluting global scope for local purposes is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your interface, it's duplicate with default type [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) of javascript

```
export interface Date { // something else, maybe myDate
    toDate: (locale: string) => string;
    toTime: (locale: string) => string;
    toDateTime: (locale: string, useText?: boolean) => string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not better: same issue